# Vagrant Up VT-X not available

Tags: laravel, vagrant, virtualbox, vagrantfile, homestead

I am in the process of installing and getting `Laravel` to work by following their installation documentation. However, when I try to vagrant up, i receive the error

> There was an error while executing VBoxManage, a CLI used by Vagrant
>   for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.
>
> Command: ["startvm", "e6f97d62-fd0b-4203-9735-9733f20d9e27", "--type",
>   "headless"]
>
> Stderr: VBoxManage: error: VT-x is not available (VERR_VMX_NO_VMX)
>   VBoxManage: error: Details: code NS_ERROR_FAILURE (0x80004005),
>   component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole

I am running the latest version of `VirtualBox` running `Ubuntu 14.04.4`. Then, I am running a Vagrant Box inside the virtualbox which gives me that error. My virtualization is enabled in the `BIOS` and my processors are able to support virtualization. I read in another thread that nested virtualization is possible if we change vb.cpus to 1. However, I think the configuration file has changed and I can't find the provider block in my Vagrant file. Does anyone know how to solve this error?

[Error VT-x not available for Vagrant machine inside Virtualbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24620599/error-vt-x-not-available-for-vagrant-machine-inside-virtualbox)

Edit: Clarification on the setup. My host is running 'Windows 10' which has a virtualbox open. This virtualbox is running Linux 'Ubuntu 14.04.4' 64bit. From here, I ran the command 'vagrant box add laravel/homestead' which creates a virtualbox Ubuntu 32 bit. Then, I run the command 'vagrant up' which gives me the above error. I'd also like to add that the acceleration tab is greyed out inside my virtualbox settings.

Comment: Can you help clarify the environment - I'm not clear how many levels of virtualization you're trying to achieve. Do you just have a Host (eg. Windows) where you're running `vagrant up` and seeing this error? Or are you already on a Guest, installing VBox/vagrant, and seeing the error from a Guest-in-a-Guest?

Comment: Hello. I have updated my post. Sorry for not clarifying clearly.

Comment: why do you need the ubuntu 32 bit within the  'Ubuntu 14.04.4' 64bit ?

Comment: I believe that is what laravel homestead uses. I'm just supposed to run ' vagrant up ' and it should allow me to access my local domain.

Comment: I think the confusion is over why you NEED to nest the virtualization. Can't you just run the homestead box from your Host as well? Why does it need to be inside another Guest?

Comment: I thought it was much easier to work in a Linux environment with Laravel rather than in Windows. Worst case scenario, I will setup Laravel on my host.

Comment: I think it would help as @BrianMorton mentions you can just run homestead from your windows host having multiple level of virtualization can bring some troubles hard to debug

Comment: Alright I think will just try that. I thought nested virtualization was possible and that I was doing something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

As per the comments on the question, I think the solution here is **not to run nested virtualization** (eg. Host -> Guest [Ubuntu 14.04-64bit] -> Guest [Ubuntu ?-32bit]).

If you just want a box to do your laravel/homestead development work in, you can boot the box/vagrant straight out of Windows, you don't need to have an intermediary Guest OS (ubuntu/trusty64 in the question).

Install Virtualbox and Vagrant in Windows, and try to vagrant up the laravel/homestead box from there. If you need a commandline in windows, you can use Powershell, Git for Windows (or Git Shell or whatever it's called), or install **[Cygwin](https://cygwin.com/) (my preferred method).**

Answer (score 0):

Just check hyper-v is not enabled/running. I had same issue after installing docker. Docker uses Windows hyper-v driver to create containers. Hence Docker and Virtual Box may not work together!