# How to avoid CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION errors with VirtualBox inside VMWare

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox, vmware, virtualization, bsod

I have the same setup as described here:

[Running Vagrant Inside VMWare VM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17175696/running-vagrant-inside-vmware-vm)

Now I'm frequently getting BSOD with a CRITICAL_STRUCTURE_CORRUPTION error and I'm wondering if I can get rid of those. I read opinions that I must expect an unstable system in this setup of nested virtualization, on the other hand it does work and people seem to be using it.

After searching for this error on the web, I already upgraded to the latest versions of VMWare Player (6.0.3 on Windows 8.1) and Virtualbox (4.3.14 on Ubuntu 14.04.1 inside VMWare) and I reduced the number of CPUs in the Vagrant Virtualbox Machine to 1, but the error still occurs, sometimes after an hour or so, and only when running the Vagrant Virtualbox inside the VMWare Player.

Anything that I could try to make it run smoothly?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: Ok, moved it to superuser: http://superuser.com/questions/790216/how-to-avoid-critical-structure-corruption-errors-with-virtualbox-inside-vmware

Answer (score 0):

Make sure Hyper-V windows resource is inactive.
This works for me

Ty